# Markdown relative path being replaced with absolute path

Tags: sublimetext2, markdown

I am creating several static web pages using Markdown in Sublime Text 2.  When I build the markdown file, it is replacing relative paths to images with absolute paths. 
I am using the Markdown Editing and Markdown Preview packages in Sublime.

Here is a minimal working example.
Consider the following file structure:

- `localdir/`

  - `dir1`

    - `file1.md`
  - `images`

    - `img1.gif`

The content of `file1.md` is

```
# File1

![Image 1](../images/img1.gif)
```

Building `file1.md` results in the following `file1.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>file1</title></head>
<body><h1 id="file-1">File 1</h1>
<p><img alt="Image 1" src="file:///Users/username/localdir/dir1/../images/img1.gif" />
</body></html>
```

Why is the relative path replaced with an absolute path?  How can this be avoided?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The MarkdownPreview plugin settings includes the property 'image_path_conversion', which accepts the following values:

- absolute
- relative
- base64
- none

You need to add this setting under `Preferences > Package Settings > Markdown Preview > Settings - User` eg

```
"image_path_conversion": "relative"
```

When you next build the markdown file, the image path will be relative to the HTML output.

There is also a 'file_path_conversions' property which can also be set to absolute/relative. Additionally, if you open the 'Settings - Default' file for the plugin, you can see all the settings which are available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview/issues/146) with the Markdown Preview plugin. There hasn't been any action for the last month or so, so I added a bump at the bottom to ask the maintainer about his progress on fixing this.